# give su privilege to specific app and no need to sudo before command

Tags: 14.04

how i can get `su` privilege to specific app and after no need to add `sudo` before that to do work ?

for example :

i must use `sudo adb devices` to `adb` work correctly with my phone.

how i can give full permission to `adb` to work without `sudo`?

i wrote an app that call adb every 1 sec for do something and i must always call `sudo` before `adb`, in `/var/log/auth.log` all `sudo` command logged and i don’t want this.

Comment: The *right* way to approach this, I think, is to create a `udev` rule that ensures your device gets attached with the appropriate permissions. See for example [Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) [developer.android.com] or [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19291975/4440445). You might also need to add your user to the `plugdev` group.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by editing the sudoers file, using `sudo visudo`

In this command-line "editor" append:

```
Username ALL = NOPASSWD: /full(!)/path/to/app
```

and replace `Username` with your username. But beware, that this is pretty dangerous, granting full sudo permission to apps, and should only be done if you know exactly what you're doing

Comment: don’t work ... this command only remove request password and i must add sudo before app .
without sudo app don’t correctly work